# Can I have multiple directories set for $HOME?

Tags: environment-variables, home

I'm wondering if I can do something like:

`export HOME=$HOME:$HOME/.configs`

So that I can keep all my custom configs in ~/.configs.

I know it's possible to set it but I'm not sure if it will cause problems down the road. Is this safe? Is there a more standard way?

Comment: Environment application are interpreted by applications (i.e. by shell `bash`), and neither of them (probably) supports this. Anyway, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know about the Y problem too. All your config files are already in the right place, where programs expect to find them. What do you intend to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, albeit possible, and experts might need this in certain rare cases, you shouldn't change the value of the `HOME` environment variable, it is set by your system.

Secondly, the content of `HOME` is expected to be one, and only one, (existing) directory: your home directory.

See what [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) about `HOME`:

> HOME: The system shall initialize this variable at the time of login to be a pathname of the user's home directory.

Answer (score 5):

The `$HOME/.config` directory is part of the [XDG Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) and is determined by the value of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.

Theoretically, this means that if you want your configuration files stored somewhere else you just need to set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to that preferred location.

In practice, however, you may well find instances of software that blindly writes to `$HOME/.config/...` rather than following the XDG Specification. Particularly as it's not a required part of any distribution.

For applications that do follow XDG, you can also have a set of directories (`$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` colon separated, like `$PATH`) that define other locations from which default values should be sourced. The default value for this should be `/etc/xdg`.

Now, the next question that should be on your lips is, "OK, so where do I set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`?" and unfortunately [this gets rather complicated](https://superuser.com/questions/365847/where-should-the-xdg-config-home-variable-be-defined).

The summary seems to be that you will probably get away with putting it in `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`), but that a global configuration via PAM might be required. Personally I've not tried this, and in particular I don't see how a `.profile` based solution could work with a GUI-based login environment.

The second question might then be "How do I move my configuration to this new location?", which is also [fraught with potential issues](https://superuser.com/questions/874901/what-are-the-step-to-move-all-your-dotfiles-into-xdg-directories). Sigh.

The easiest option here is probably to use a symbolic link that points `$HOME/.config` to your preferred location. This handles not only any issues with setting `$XDG_CONFIG_DIR` but also any issues with applications that insist on looking directly under `$HOME/.config`.

```
cd
test -d .config && mv .config .config_old
ln -s /path/to/preferred_config_dir .config
```